Emit gets stuck while another thread is being executed
This is a Flask Socket-io  App, In this particular code, A stream of response is being carried out by an AI model and chunks are being emitted regularly.
The issue here is that the Emit gets called successfully for each chunk but is not received by the front end unless the previous thread is finished.
I have tried different methods , different threading, Thread pooling, concurrent.futures, Background threads, Celery and Radius Server but no progress is achieved. The problem is something else like configuration and stuff.
Help is really appreciated. Loosing my patience over here.
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            static_folder=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))

CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", ping_timeout=120)

class CaseChat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = global_models.model
        self.spec_generator = global_models.spec_generator
        self.model_gtts = global_models.model_gtts
        self.bytes_audio = []
def predict(self, **kwargs):
    recipient_id = kwargs['recipient_id']
    history = kwargs.get('history', [])
    self.bytes_audio = []
    try:
        history.append({'role': 'user', 'content': kwargs.get('chunks') + str(kwargs.get("interview_time", ' '))})
        inputs = global_models.tokenizer.apply_chat_template(history, add_generation_prompt=True, tokenize=False)
        inputs = inputs.replace('''\n\nCutting Knowledge Date: December 2023\nToday Date: 26 Jul 2024\n\n''', "")
        inputs = global_models.tokenizer(inputs, return_tensors='pt').to('cuda')
        streamer = TextIteratorStreamer(global_models.tokenizer, skip_prompt=True, skip_special_tokens=True)
        generation_kwargs = dict(inputs, streamer=streamer, max_new_tokens=512)
        thread_generate = Thread(target=global_models.model.generate, kwargs=generation_kwargs)
        thread_generate.start()
        new_text = ""
        for output in streamer:
            if user_data[recipient_id]['interrupt']:
                break
            if not output.strip("\n"):
                continue
            if not len(new_text):
                if new_text.startswith('assistant'):
                    new_text = new_text[9:]
                elif new_text.startswith('user'):
                    new_text = new_text[4:]
            new_text += output
            if len(new_text.split(' ')) > 5:
                history = self.response(history, new_text, kwargs.get('s_id'))
                new_text = ""
        if len(new_text) and not user_data[recipient_id]['interrupt']:
            history = self.response(history, new_text, kwargs.get('s_id'))
        audio_saver(path=f"{save_location}/{recipient_id}/{user_data[recipient_id]['time_duration']}-AI.wav",
                    audio=self.bytes_audio)
        return history
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Prediction failed: {str(e)}")
        history.pop(-1)
        return history

def response(self, history, new_text, s_id):
    new_text = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', new_text)
    self.speak(new_text, s_id)
    # print("Test receieved by response" + new_text)
    if 'assistant' != history[-1]['role']:
        history.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': new_text})
    else:
        history[-1]['content'] += new_text
    return history

def speak(self, text, s_id):
    try:
        ai_text = text.split("AI:")[-1].strip()

        self.spec_generator.eval()

        parsed = self.spec_generator.parse(ai_text)
        spectrogram = self.spec_generator.generate_spectrogram(tokens=parsed)
        audio = self.model_gtts.convert_spectrogram_to_audio(spec=spectrogram)
        audio = audio.detach()
        audio_np = audio.cpu().numpy().squeeze()

        with io.BytesIO() as bytesio:
            sf.write(bytesio, audio_np, 22050, format="wav", subtype="PCM_16")
            bytesio.seek(0)
            audio_data = bytesio.read()


            socketio.emit('response', audio_data, to=s_id)
            print("Text streamed outwards: " + text)
            self.bytes_audio.append(audio_data)
            return "Request received and task started", 202
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("TTS conversion failed", e)
        return f"Error: {e}", 500
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True, use_reloader=False, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True,
                 log_output=True)


What method of concurrency are you using in your app? If you are using eventlet or gevent, then you are likely to have issues if you mix that with threads. In that case I suggest you switch to the threading async_mode for your Socket.IO app so that it is compatible with your other threading stuff.

I am also facing the similar issue, I am using gthreads and async_mode is configured to threading. It works fine for 1 or 2 days, then suddenly an emit() gets stuck.
Did you managed to solve it ?

I was able to bypass this problem by streaming output from llama using llama_cpp, that uses a separate compiler to process the output, Instead of Threads or any other python process.
